# How to concatenate two 2D arrays in parallel by returning a 1D array

Tags: python

How to concatenate two 2D arrays in parallel by returning a 1D array, example:

**ARRAYS / LISTS**

```
list1 = [['a'], ['b'], ['c']]

list2 = [['A'], ['B'], ['C']]
```

**GOAL:**

```
list3 = ['a:A', 'b:B', 'c:C']
```

**Attempt:**

```
concat_array = [itm + ':' if not itm.endswith (':') plus itm for itm in list1 + list2]
```

Comment: what should happen when for example: `list1 = [['a', 'd', 'e'], ['b'], ['c']]`?

Comment: What do you means with "parallel"???

Comment: Can join ['ade']

Comment: Parallel = (list3 = list1 + ":" + list2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
def join_2d_arrays(a, b, separator=":"):
    for x, y in zip(a, b):
        yield separator.join(itertools.chain(x, y))
```

http://ideone.com/H8ZcbT

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
[itm1[0] + ':' + itm2[0] for itm1,itm2 in zip(list1, list2)]
```

Edit:
Checked and it worked

Answer (score 1):

You can concate lists like this for example:

```
list1 = [['a'], ['b'], ['c']]

list2 = [['A'], ['B'], ['C']]

list3 = []
for itm1,itm2 in zip(list1, list2):
    list3.append(itm1[0] + ':' + itm2[0])
```

Gets you:

```
list3 = ['a:A', 'b:B', 'c:C']
```